# vhdl share variables in a package file

Tags: vhdl, simulation, test-bench

I am currently making code for frame generator which I and others need to generate data though some VHDL logic in simulation.

For this I have created at package file where I have a Generator procedure and a Monitor Procedure.

Since I like the Idea of a protected type and I for obvious reason cannot put a signal generator and monitor into a protected type I've just created them in the package file as mentioned above, also I've created additional procedures and functions to initialize and help setup different aspects of the Generator and Monitor.

For this to work, Where in a protected type you can have variables which are visible inside the whole protect type, I am using shared variables. Now this is a problem and some simulators will give you a warning.

Now to make these variable somewhat safe and remove these warnings I've made protected variables.

lets take a boolean value which are most common in my code.

**Package**

```
subtype st_pBool is boolean;

type pBoolean is protected

   procedure Set (
     constant invar : in st_pBool
   );

   impure function Get return st_pBool;

end protected pBoolean;

shared variable GenUseRandom : pBoolean;
```

**Package Body**

```
type pBoolean is protected body

  variable var : st_pBool;

   procedure Set (
     constant invar : in st_pBool
   ) is
   begin
     var := invar;
   end procedure Set;

   impure function Get return st_pBool is
   begin
     return var;
   end Get;

end protected body pBoolean;
```

I've used the Idea of getter and setter from others languages, to set and get values from this protected type

```
GenUseRandom.Set(False)

if GenUseRandom.Get then
  do something intelligent here
end if;
```

Is this idea good? 
Does it do what I think it does IE preventing multiple updates to the same variable in different processes, or am I just masking the problem the simulators warn me about.

Regards
Anders

Comment: Looks good for simulation. Don't expect it to be synthesisable, but I can't tell whether that matters to you from the question.

Comment: For frame generation like that, you may consider using a combination of a shared variable, that contains the data provided by the test procedures, in combination with a continuous procedure call, that consumes data from the shared variable and generate the cycle accurate signals.  The protected type for the shared variable and the declaration and implementation of the procedure can be put in the same package for easy maintenance and use.  (Tag et kig på DAU CPU IF test generatoren jeg skrev for nogle år siden; KNH kan hjælpe med at finde den...  God weekend ;-)

Comment: @ Brian It is only for simulation.

Comment: @ Morten I will take a look. However they are all in the same package. It is only a question to safeguard the shared variables since they can be called from multiple processes in the main testbench